# Getting the two minimum values from a list in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml, folding

I need to write a function twoMin: int list → int * int using foldl that returns the two smallest values (not elements) of a list. You may assume that the list contains at least two elements with different values.

```
let rec foldl f l acc = match l with
  | [] -> acc
  | x :: xs -> foldl f xs (f x acc)

let twoMin lst =
  match lst with
  | [] | [_] -> failwith "List must contain at least two elements with different 
values."
   | x :: y :: rest ->
    let initial_acc = if x < y then (x, y) else (y, x) in
    let (min1, min2) = foldl (fun a b -> if b < fst a then (b, fst a) else if b < snd 
a then (fst a, b) else a) rest initial_acc in
    (min1, min2)
```

I keep getting error and I do not know what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Please be more specific about the errors you are getting.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You can write `let twoMin = function x::y::rest -> ... | _ -> failwith "error"`. No need to name the argument if you just match it and no need to list all the error cases if you match them last.

Answer (score 2):

*You're close.*

The accumulator you're passing to `foldl` is a tuple of two values. This is fine. However, the result of the function you pass to `foldl` must have the same type as the accumulator. If we take your code and change some of the names:

```
let twoMin lst =
  match lst with
  | [] | [_] -> failwith "List must contain at least two elements with different values."
  | x :: y :: rest ->
    let initial_acc = if x < y then (x, y) else (y, x) in
    let (min1, min2) = 
      foldl 
        (fun x acc -> 
           if acc < fst x then (acc, fst x) 
           else if acc < snd x then (fst x, acc) 
           else x) 
        rest 
        initial_acc 
    in
    (min1, min2)
```

We can see that you're treating each element of the list as the accumulator, and vice versa.

Using `fst` and `snd` like this is annoying when we can just use pattern-matching.

```
let twoMin lst =
  match lst with
  | [] | [_] -> failwith "List must contain at least two elements with different 
values."
   | x :: y :: rest ->
    let initial_acc = if x < y then (x, y) else (y, x) in
    let (min1, min2) = 
      foldl 
        (fun x (min1, min2 as acc) -> 
           if x < min1 then (x, min1) 
           else if x < min2 then (min1, x) 
           else acc) 
        rest 
        initial_acc 
    in
    (min1, min2)
```

Of course, pattern-matching that tuple, then just rebuilding it and returning it immediately is pointless.

Also, your confusion may be aided by your definition of a left fold, which differs from `List.fold_left`. Try instead:

```
let rec foldl f init = 
  function
  | [] -> init
  | x::xs -> foldl f (f init x) xs
```